# When returning an object, I can't simply use {} after class name

Tags: c++, return

Taking this educational code about nested classes as an example:

```
class enclose {
    struct nested { // private member
        void g() {}
    };  
public:
    static nested f() { return nested{}; } 
};   

int main() {
    //enclose::nested n1 = e.f(); // error: 'nested' is private

    enclose::f().g(); // OK: does not name 'nested'
    auto n2 = enclose::f(); // OK: does not name 'nested'
    n2.g(); }
```

When copy and pasting this code to Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, I get an error in the line

```
static nested f() { return nested{}; }
```

in which the problem is regarding the way the function is returning nested. This isn't the first time I've seen codes returning a value this way, but I usually ignore it and do it the longer way. Is this a compiler issue?

Comment: It is interesting that `auto` can bind an identifier to a `nested` when an identifier can't be defined as such. Its almost like `auto` is circumventing class access rules.

Comment: @vsoftco just looked at features from c++11 compiler the visual studio 2012 edition has implemented and yes, it is incomplete, therefore i can assume it is a compiler issue, seems like i need to update my tools. Thanks

Comment: @Galik now that you mention it, its true, nested class supposedly follows member access specifiers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
return nested{};
```

employs the new C++11 [braced-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) and [value-initializes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) the object. As you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368(v=vs.110).aspx), braced-initialization is not supported in Visual Studio 2012 (VC11), so you get a compile-time error.

The only solution is to use

```
return nested();
```

instead, or update your compiler.